# How to disable 'window resize' shortcut keys?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10

In Windows 10, when you try to resize a window with the shortcut of <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>, it allows you to select which program to resize on the opposite side. This is a neat feature.

However, I was wondering if we are able to disable this? A registry key or in settings?

Comment: @miroxlav Thanks for the edit! I will take those pointers when I post other questions in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the settings app, go to `system -> multitasking` and turn off the setting "`When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it`"

[image]